# Why dosent my tableview show search results?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview, uisearchbar

I'm trying to accomplish searching for other users only when the user has typed at least 2 words, and only then begin the search in the database (because I don't want to scan the entire database for the users). I had some problems with 2 letter search, but I think I got the code (thanks to user Jay).

However when I run it in the simulator, the console prints name, but nothing shows up in the tableview? (its empty).

Do you know what I have done wrong?

This is my code:

```
class FollowUsersTableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    private var viewIsHiddenObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    var usersArray = [UserModel]()
    var filteredUsers = [UserModel]()
    var loggedInUser: User?
    //
    var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    //usikker på den koden over

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self


        //large title
        self.title = "Discover"
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        self.tableView?.delegate = self
        self.tableView?.dataSource = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.delegate = self;



        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar



    }

    func searchUsers(text: String) {
        if text.count >= 2 {
            self.usersArray = [] //clear the array each time
            let endingText = text + "\u{f8ff}"
            databaseRef.child("profile").queryOrdered(byChild: "username")
                .queryStarting(atValue: text)
                .queryEnding(atValue: endingText)
                .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                    for child in snapshot.children {
                        let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
                        print(childSnap)
                        let userObj =  Mapper<UserModel>().map(JSONObject: childSnap.value!)
                        userObj?.uid = childSnap.key
                        if childSnap.key != self.loggedInUser?.uid { //ignore this user
                            self.usersArray.append(userObj!)

                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
        }
    } //may need an else statement here to clear the array when there is no text


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let dest = segue.destination as! UserProfileViewController
        let obj = sender as! UserModel
        let dict = ["uid": obj.uid!, "username": obj.username!, "photoURL": obj.photoURL, "bio": obj.bio]
        dest.selectedUser = dict as [String : Any]
    }





}

// MARK: - tableview methods
extension FollowUsersTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchController.searchBar.text!.count >= 2 ? filteredUsers.count : 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FollowTableViewCell

        let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]

        cell.title?.text = user.username
        if let url = URL(string: user.photoURL ?? "") {
            cell.userImage?.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user_male"), options: .progressiveDownload, completed: nil)
            cell.userImage.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
            cell.userImage.sd_showActivityIndicatorView()
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "user", sender: self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row])
    }



}

// MARK: - search methods
extension FollowUsersTableViewController:UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {



    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false

        self.searchUsers(text: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)

        filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func filterContent(searchText:String){

        if searchText.count >= 2{


            self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
                return(user.username!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 arrays `usersArray` and `filteredUsers`

```
if childSnap.key != self.loggedInUser?.uid { //ignore this user
       self.usersArray.append(userObj!)
}
...
 self.tableView.reloadData()
```

so the the above reload has no effect as you always use

```
let user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
```

in `cellForRowAt` , in such cases you should have a var like

```
var isSearching = false
```

and alter it when you search then in all delegate & dataSource methods

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return isSearching ? filteredUsers.count : usersArray.count
 }
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FollowTableViewCell

    let user = isSearching ? filteredUsers[indexPath.row] : usersArray[indexPath.row] 
  .....
 }

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    isSearching = true
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    isSearching = false
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    isSearching = false
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    isSearching = false
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filteredUsers = usersArray.filter { /* do filter */ }

    if(filteredUsers.count == 0){
        isSearching = false
    } else {
        isSearching = true
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "user", sender: isSearching ? self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row] : self.usersArray[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. However im not really sure i understand what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: Okay i see it a bit more clearly, good thinking with the isSearching. However what you want me to do with my function "func filterContent"? since we are doing the filtering in textDidchange

Comment: i think you need to replace it with call to `searchUsers`

Comment: i added this `self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
            return(user.username!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))`

Comment: to your /* do filter */

Comment: this accomplishes a local search , but for remote i think you need to show a loader

Comment: Now the tableview works, but it only works when i search for usernames that have a Uppercase begining. So "Makelele" gets displayed with picture and name, however "mattgilbert" dosent show up. Even though i only type "ma"

Comment: Also when i tested it, it began showing two rows of the same user "Makelele", and also when i clicked on the profile i get  `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`

Comment: Do you have a solution to that?

Comment: i changed it from `self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row] : self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row]` to `self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row] : self.usersArray[indexPath.row]` now it works. But the user still is in the tableview , when i go back, even though the searchBar is empty

Comment: Also it seems when i write more than two words now, for instance "Mak" the user gets two rows, and it still should only be one

Comment: check if you have duplicates

Comment: Also its only the username that starts with a Uppercase that gets displayed and not the usernames that start with lowercase

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates? There is only one user with that name in my database

Comment: username is only first name ? , may be search exists in first and last names ?

Comment: no its usernames. His first name is James, and when i write "Ma" only he is showing up. Because he is the only one with an Uppercase username. How can i make the search work for both uppercase and lowercase usernames?

Answer (score 1):

This code is very close, and as the other answer points out you've got two arrays.

But let's really simplify the issue: You only need one array since you are filtering Firebase, not the array.

In other words when a user types into the searchField, you're querying Firebase for results and putting them into an array. *That's* the same array you should be using as the dataSource for your tableView.

As your code sits, you're filtering Firebase and then filtering those results *again* which isn't needed.

So at a high level supposed we have four users in our database

```
Larry
Moe
Monroe
Curly
```

the user types 'Mo' into the search field which causes your Fire query to execute. It will return two results:

```
Mo
Monroe
```

which then gets populated into an array - we'll call it userResultsArray.

then

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

which then calls the tableView delegate methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection
   return userResultsArray.count
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
   get the user from userResultsArray
   return the user name
```

As shown, you only need the single array to store the queried (filtered) results from Firebase.

Comment: thanks again Jay, explained it good. However i did what Sh_Khan said, and the search now works, however i have two problems: 1.  if i type more than two words it will reload the data and show "Makelele" in two tableview cells.  2. The search only works for usernames that has Uppercase starting letter, and it dosent show all the other users (which has lowercase usernames). Do you know whats wrong?

Comment: Also after i have searched for a user, and canceled the search (at the searchbar), the profile is still in the tableview.

Comment: @MattGilbert That solution doesn't directly address your question or the code in your question. It's not wrong by any means but it's a totally different direction and solution than what's in your question. If you want to load *all* the users and filter in code then it's a perfect fit. However, if you have thousands of users it could potentially overwhelm the device. If you are using queries (as outlined in your code) that's not an issue. It depends on what direction you want to go. a) Load ALL users and filter in code or b) Use queries to limit and return results.

Comment: Thing is im only looking for å way to search for users in my Firebase database for my social media app. I dont want to get huge firebase bills if i have alot of users in my App, so im depending on a good way to do the queries. Will my current code with Sh_Khan´s inputs do that the best way?

Comment: @MattGilbert Nope. That code rely's on loading all of your users in and filtering in code. That being said, it's a good answer for that type of solution, and a consideration should be made that once you load your users you don't have to load them again, so performing queries would hit Firebase more frequently but you are limiting the data you're returning with each keystroke.

Comment: How can i only load relevant users? i want my app to be scaleable and not get a big bill from firebase :S

Comment: @MattGilbert I think you already know how as the code in your question will query Firebase for users whose names start with the first two chars typed in and return all matches.

Comment: Yeah but im confused, you said IT will query every user in the database, and then filter

Comment: But do you mean that if i type «Ma», It would only load users Mathias, Matt, and Makelele. And not load the user «Fredric» at all, so im only paying for 3 loads in this case?

Comment: @MattGilbert That's what the code in your question is supposed to be doing, yes. It will query all names that start with *Ma* and end with *Ma\u{f8ff}*. I didn't test your code but the last question you asked and I provided an answer does just that. You had not accepted my previous answer so perhaps it wasn't correct, however you appear to be using the code I provided. Take a look at [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974684/how-can-i-use-querystartingatvalue-in-my-searchcontroller-to-search-for-users) for reference. Perhaps we don't understand what you're asking?

Comment: Awesome, then im on the right path. Yeah i just forgot to accept your answer, did it now though. However for every question and answer i get on stackoverflow, i get one step closer to what im trying to achieve, however i always get some bugs along the way. Im asking a new question about the duplicates in my tableview now, and also about the word counter stuff.