# Searchfield and tableview - showing only users with uppercase usernames

Tags: swift, firebase, tableview, uisearchbar

I have a searchfield in my app, where users can search for other users. However i have three issues with it:

1. right now the search only works for users that have a uppercase username. So for instance when i search "Ma", the only user that is showing is "Makelele" because his username has a uppercase letter as the first letter. For instance "mattgilbert" isnt showing at all, even though i should be on the tableview.
2. when the user has appered in the tableview, the user is still in the tableview, even though i have canceled the search.
3. i have it so the search for users only begins when the user has typed atleast 2 words, however if a user types more than that into the searchfield the user will just dissapear in the tableview. And i have to search more letters in order for the user to appear again.

It would mean alot if someone could help me out on this, as i have used alot of time on this search stuff. I want it to be as cost effiecent as possible, and at the same time be scaleable (hence why i have this two letters atleast typed before the database runs its query)

This is my code:

```
class FollowUsersTableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var isSearching = false

    private var viewIsHiddenObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    var usersArray = [UserModel]()
    var filteredUsers = [UserModel]()
    var loggedInUser: User?
    //
    var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    //usikker på den koden over

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self


        //large title
        self.title = "Discover"
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        self.tableView?.delegate = self
        self.tableView?.dataSource = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.delegate = self;



        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        //self.loadProfileData()

       //self.searchBar(searchController.searchBar, textDidChange: searchController.searchBar.text)







    }





    func searchUsers(text: String) {
        if text.count >= 2 {
            self.usersArray = [] //clear the array each time
            let endingText = text + "\u{f8ff}"
            databaseRef.child("profile").queryOrdered(byChild: "username")
                .queryStarting(atValue: text)
                .queryEnding(atValue: endingText)
                .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                    for child in snapshot.children {
                        let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
                        print(childSnap)
                        let userObj =  Mapper<UserModel>().map(JSONObject: childSnap.value!)
                        userObj?.uid = childSnap.key
                        if childSnap.key != self.loggedInUser?.uid { //ignore this user
                            self.usersArray.append(userObj!)

                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
        }
    } //may need an else statement here to clear the array when there is no text


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let dest = segue.destination as! UserProfileViewController
        let obj = sender as! UserModel
        let dict = ["uid": obj.uid!, "username": obj.username!, "photoURL": obj.photoURL, "bio": obj.bio]
        dest.selectedUser = dict as [String : Any]
    }





}

// MARK: - tableview methods
extension FollowUsersTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return isSearching ? filteredUsers.count : usersArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FollowTableViewCell

        let user = isSearching ? filteredUsers[indexPath.row] : usersArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.title?.text = user.username
        if let url = URL(string: user.photoURL ?? "") {
            cell.userImage?.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user_male"), options: .progressiveDownload, completed: nil)
            cell.userImage.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
            cell.userImage.sd_showActivityIndicatorView()
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "user", sender: isSearching ? self.filteredUsers[indexPath.row] : self.usersArray[indexPath.row])
    }



}

// MARK: - search methods
extension FollowUsersTableViewController:UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {



    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false

        self.searchUsers(text: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)

        filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func filterContent(searchText:String){

        if searchText.count >= 2{


            self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
                return(user.username!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
            }
        }
    }


    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        isSearching = true
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        isSearching = false
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        isSearching = false
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        isSearching = false
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
            return(user.username!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
        }


        if(filteredUsers.count == 0){
            isSearching = false
        } else {
            isSearching = true
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


}
```

**EDIT: Updated Code**

```
class FollowUsersTableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var isSearching = false

    private var viewIsHiddenObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    var usersArray = [UserModel]()

    var loggedInUser: User?
    //
    var databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    //usikker på den koden over

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self


        //large title
        self.title = "Discover"
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        self.tableView?.delegate = self
        self.tableView?.dataSource = self
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.delegate = self;



        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        //self.loadProfileData()

       //self.searchBar(searchController.searchBar, textDidChange: searchController.searchBar.text)



    }


    func searchUsers(text: String) {
        if text.count >= 2 {
            self.usersArray = [] //clear the array each time
            let endingText = text + "\u{f8ff}"
            databaseRef.child("profile").queryOrdered(byChild: "username")
                .queryStarting(atValue: text)
                .queryEnding(atValue: endingText)
                .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

                    for child in snapshot.children {
                        let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
                        print(childSnap)
                        let userObj =  Mapper<UserModel>().map(JSONObject: childSnap.value!)
                        userObj?.uid = childSnap.key
                        if childSnap.key != self.loggedInUser?.uid { //ignore this user
                            self.usersArray.append(userObj!)

                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
        }
    } //may need an else statement here to clear the array when there is no text


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let dest = segue.destination as! UserProfileViewController
        let obj = sender as! UserModel
        let dict = ["uid": obj.uid!, "username": obj.username!, "photoURL": obj.photoURL, "bio": obj.bio]
        dest.selectedUser = dict as [String : Any]
    }





}

// MARK: - tableview methods
extension FollowUsersTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return usersArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FollowTableViewCell

        let user = usersArray[indexPath.row]

        cell.title?.text = user.username
        if let url = URL(string: user.photoURL ?? "") {
            cell.userImage?.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "user_male"), options: .progressiveDownload, completed: nil)
            cell.userImage.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
            cell.userImage.sd_showActivityIndicatorView()
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "user", sender:  self.usersArray[indexPath.row])
    }



}

// MARK: - search methods
extension FollowUsersTableViewController:UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {



    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        searchController.searchResultsController?.view.isHidden = false

        self.searchUsers(text: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)

        //filterContent(searchText: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
/*
    func filterContent(searchText:String){

        if searchText.count >= 2{


            self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
                return(user.username!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
            }
        }
    }
  */

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        isSearching = true
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        isSearching = false
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {


        isSearching = false

        self.usersArray = []

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        isSearching = false
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        self.usersArray.filter{ user in
            return(user.username!.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
        }


        if(usersArray.count == 0){
            isSearching = false
        } else {
            isSearching = true
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


}
```

Comment: note this `self.searchUsers(text: self.searchController.searchBar.text!)` is asynchronous` so result doesn't appear directly when the user types , i see to comment the containing function `updateSearchResults` and use only `textDidChange ` as not to mix filters at the same time

Comment: Please limit questions to one question - multiple questions make it really hard to answer.

Comment: Some advice... *I want it to be as cost effiecent as possible* is understandable but right now you've got some basic functionality to make work and a bit of a learning curve on how tableViews and dataSources work. I would suggest  gaining that understanding first - then worry about the cost component later. Once there's a clear understanding, it will help make cost-level decisions a lot easier and clearer because you'll better understand the available options. It will make questions like *should I load my data and filter in code or query firebase for a smaller dataset* much easier to answer.

Comment: Oh - as a side note; the code in your question will not work. You're filtering using Firebase queries and then and then filtering again in code that filtered data. In other words in the user types *Ma* then Firebase is going to retrieve all users that start with *Ma* and return those results but you're then filtering again for users that start with *Ma* and probably messing up the dataSource Array. This was pointed out in the last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54111912/why-dosent-my-tableview-show-search-results) and hasn't been corrected.

Comment: Oh okay, maybe this is the reason. How do you suggest to correct it my friend? :)

Comment: The way to correct it is to utilize the existing answers and use one technique: either load all the users and filter in code, or use Firebase queries to filter and return small datasets, not both. My below aswer, along with the answer I previously provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974684/how-can-i-use-querystartingatvalue-in-my-searchcontroller-to-search-for-users) as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54111912/why-dosent-my-tableview-show-search-results) is one option. You've combined the two aforementioned unrelated techniques so get rid of one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this It may helps you.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    let filteredArray = usersArray.filter { ($0["username"] as! String).range(of: searchText!, options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]) != nil }
}
```

It may helps you.Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i get  error **Type 'UserModel' has no subscript members**

Comment: That's a very efficient solution but you have to replace `($0["username"] as! String)` with `$0.username!`

Answer (score 0):

The answer to question #1

> 1) right now the search only works for users that have a uppercase
>   username. So for instance when i search "Ma", the only user that is
>   showing is "Makelele" because his username has a uppercase letter as
>   the first letter. For instance "mattgilbert" isnt showing at all, even
>   though i should be on the tableview.

Firebase doesn't have any kind of uppercase or lowercase search. It just has a literal string query that's case sensitive

The typical solution is to store a 'display' version of your strings and then a 'search' version of your strings were the string is lowercased in code before storing it in Firbease. So for example, here's a users node

```
users
  uid_0
    display_name: "Kirk"
    search_name: "kirk"
  uid_1
    display_name: "Spock"
    search_name: "spock"
  uid_1
    display_name: "Montgomery Scott"
    search_name: "montgomery scott"
```

> 2 when the user has appered in the tableview, the user is still in the
>   tableview, even though i have canceled the search.

If a search is canceled, the dataSource array should be cleared and your tableView reloaded.

```
myDataSourceArray = [] 
self.reloadTableview
```

> 3 i have it so the search for users only begins when the user has
>   typed atleast 2 words, however if a user types more than that into the
>   searchfield the user will just dissapear in the tableview. And i have
>   to search more letters in order for the user to appear again.

The code I posted in [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52974684/how-can-i-use-querystartingatvalue-in-my-searchcontroller-to-search-for-users) solves this and is a complete, tested solution. Please refer back to those answers - you can almost copy and paste the code into a project and it will work.

Comment: Hello again Jay, thanks for another awesome answer! I misunderstood you when you told me about the two array thing - but i have corrected it now, and the search works awesome. Thanks! However when i type the whole name, it still gets shown as two rows (the same user in two rows) why is this? I updated my question with my new code

Comment: @MattGilbert You've still got pieces and parts of unneeded code hanging out. For example; in the searchBar textDidChange function; you're filtering the users array *self.usersArray.filter* which you should never need to do as it will only ever contain already filtered users - your Firebase query is filtering them already. There's a *isFiltering* var around as well that't not needed - you start filtering when the user has entered two letters and will be cleared when they click the cancel button. That code needs to be cleaned up and shortened. Fixing those issues may correct the two row issue.

Comment: Hi again Jay, i have now remove the filtering in the searchBar textDidChange, and tried, and it still is showing double rows for every user when i type. I also tried removing the whole textDidChange, and that didnt work either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It only happens when i type fast, if i type slow , then it will show the correct rows.

Comment: @MattGilbert So we are getting off topic as that issue is unrelated to the question. I would suggesting posting a question about why double lines are showing in your tableview. If you do post that question, ensure you include what you've done to troubleshoot etc as it could get marked to close for 'why is this code not working'.